# IF ISNUMBER SEARCH

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate a `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(` within VBA to automatically populate cells when a user puts a code in to a cell.

I am getting an error when doing this.

The code I am currently using is:
`Range("J19") = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""IWA"",""I19"")),""IWA"",""Not Working"")")`

I have 3 sheets to look up and match, so if I19 contains IWA or IWK I need it to look at that particular sheet. At the moment I am getting NOT Working as the formula result.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `""I19""` is the text "I19", not the range.

Comment: Are you just trying to see if the cell value equals one of those? Use `InStr` or `=`. May help if you share some more context as to what you are trying to do

Comment: BigBen - How do I select the range? I am using the same formula I would use in a standard cell.

Comment: urdearboy - I have an order form, this has 4 drop down dependent boxes, where the user can select a category, and then a product. However I have a cell where if the user knows the product code, they can put that in, and the idea is that the VBA ignores the drops downs and then places the product using Index and Match.

Answer (score 0):

Via trial and method, I ended up using a If/ElseIf code like below:

```
Sub MatchI19()
If Range("J19").Value = "IWA" Then
Range("K19").Value = "IWA"
ElseIf Range("J19").Value = "IWK" Then
Range("K19").Value = "IWK"
ElseIf Range("J19").Value = "IWVD" Then
Range("K19").Value = "IWVD"
End If
End Sub
Sub IndexMatchI19()
If Range("K19").Value = "IWA" Then
Range("L19") = "=INDEX(IWA!C:C,MATCH(I19,IWA!E:E,0))"
Range("M19") = "=INDEX(IWA!B:B,MATCH(I19,IWA!E:E,0))"
Range("N19") = "=INDEX(IWA!F:F,MATCH(I19,IWA!E:E,0))"
ElseIf Range("K19").Value = "IWK" Then
Range("L19") = "=INDEX(IWK!C:C,MATCH(I19,IWK!E:E,0))"
Range("M19") = "=INDEX(IWK!B:B,MATCH(I19,IWK!E:E,0))"
Range("N19") = "=INDEX(IWK!F:F,MATCH(I19,IWK!E:E,0))"
End If
End Sub
```